# SQL Server: What does 1 ++ 2 mean?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax

SQL Server's T-SQL syntax seems to allow multiple plus signs in succession:

```
SELECT 1 + 2 --3
SELECT 1 ++ 2 --3
SELECT 1 ++++++ 2 --3
SELECT 1 + '2' --3
SELECT 1 ++ '2' --3
SELECT '1' + '2' --'12'
SELECT '1' ++ '2' --'12'
```

Multiple pluses seem to behave just like a single plus. Why does the "multiple plus operator" `++` exist? What does it do?

Comment: `SELECT + 'A string'` is [discussed here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/718176/concatenation-operator-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first plus sign is interpreted as an addition operator. Each of the remaining plus signs is interpreted as a [unary plus operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174362.aspx):

```
1 ++ 2   means   1 + (+2)
1 +++ 2  means   1 + (+(+2))
```

It's very common in programming languages to have this unary plus operator, though it's rarely used in SQL as it doesn't actually do anything.

> Although a unary plus can appear before any numeric expression, it performs no operation on the value returned from the expression. Specifically, it will not return the positive value of a negative expression.

The unary plus operator is mentioned in the SQL-92 standard.

> As well as the usual arithmetic operators, plus, minus, times, divide, **unary plus**, and unary minus, there are the following functions that return numbers: ...

While unary plus isn't all that useful, it has a more useful companion: unary minus. It is also known as the [negative operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189480.aspx).

```
SELECT -(expression), ...
--     ^ unary minus
```

Comment: It seems the `Last` (rightmost) plus sign is interpreted as addition, and all others as unary operators. `SELECT 5 - - + 1` evaluates to 6

Comment: @KhalidAmin no, that would be interpreted as 5 - (-(+1)), which is also 6. Binary + is left associative.

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT 1 ++ 2`  means 1 plus (+2) which means 3

Same logic for the others `1+(+(+2))` and so on

`SELECT '1' + '2' --'12'` you are concatenating 2 strings, string '1' and string '2', which results '12'