# Why does this work in SSMS?

Tags: sql, ssms

I was in a database class the other night and we noticed that the following code seemed to work, but we could not logically understand why.

```
DECLARE @counter  integer
SET @counter = 42
WHILE @counter < 52
BEGIN 
    set @counter = @counter+++++ + 1
    PRINT 'The counter is ' + cast(@counter as char) 
END
```

We realized that we could add any number of +'s on to our @counter variable, and SSMS does not seem to care, even though it does not match the original variable. Anybody happen to know why this works?

Comment: Interesting. If you change it to `+-1` it goes into an infinite loop. If you change it to `+-+-+1` it also works.

Comment: You might find [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174362(v=sql.110).aspx) helpful.  Basically, I'm guessing that only the first "+" is evaluated and all other "+"s are treated as "this is a positive number." So ++1 is the same as +Positive1

Answer (score 0):

Appending a **+** to a variable name does not change the variable name, as white space is ignored (and **+** is not a valid character in a variable name anyway).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464831/sql-server-what-does-1-2-mean) for a discussion about why multiple **+** signs works.  Essentially, every **+** (or **-**) after the first one is considered a unary operator.