# Why does this work in SQL Server? (@counter+++++ + 1)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, ssms-2012

Why does this kind-of work in SSMS and does not produce a squiggle or a run-time error?

```
DECLARE @counter  integer
SET @counter = 42
WHILE @counter < 52
BEGIN 
    set @counter = @counter++++++++  + 1
    PRINT 'The counter is ' + cast(@counter as char) 
END
```

Comment: I swear I've read it somewhere. Edit: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10464848/2203084) might help.

Comment: @FelixPamittan - Nice catch